# What are the general risks when synchronizing thread pools and asynchronous tasks?

Tags: multithreading, asynchronous, concurrency, synchronization, task

I heard that memory overflow can happen, when the thread pool tries to create new thread to replace blocked threads. What to look for when synchronizing thread pool? Sources appreciated.

Comment: Creating a new thread to replace a blocked thread does not solve the problem that caused the blocked thread to become blocked. When threads are blocked it is usually because they are waiting for a blocking function to complete or the system has a deadlock or a live lock. Also, synchronization itself involves blocking threads to avoid race conditions.

Comment: _when the thread pool tries to create new thread to replace blocked threads_: what thread pools do things like that? Do you know any existing TP with such logic?

Comment: answer in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62028011/synchronization-in-java-forkjoinpool-compute-method

Comment: This applies to the `ForkJoinPool`, not to thread pools in general. Further, even the `ForkJoinPool` does not detect when a thread uses `synchronized` or is otherwise blocked, the operation has to implement `ForkJoinPool.ManagedBlocker` appropriately to make the pool create compensation threads.